# How can i store an element value using a class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I store the value of this element using it's class. I had worked on different concepts but it didn't worked

```
## Html##
output is my class here
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>
## jquery ##
var ar_value = $('.output').val(); /*--is this correct--*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get this `undefined` value because you have some classes for many elements
**try with** :

```js
$('.col-sm-10.ac').find('.output').each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" value='2'>2</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to get the attribute of 'value,' you have to use attr()

```
var ar_value = $('.output').attr('value');
```

If this element is unique, you should use 'id' instead of 'class,' as with class, there maybe likely more than one in the DOM. Moreover, the use of .val() is:

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. When called on an empty
>   collection, it returns undefined.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: Not to mention if it's a class they are trying to get a value from there is likely to be more than one.

Comment: Dear kjy 112 even though it is saying undefined

Comment: @naniraju try putting your js codes inside ready. Example for jQuery: 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
}); and place your javascripts inside of <header></header>. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Works perfectly fine. @naniraju if your are still getting undefined, please make sure your trying to read value after the DOM of the element is constructed and ready to use. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/218514/

Comment: @naniraju, You can also check if element is ready to use by using ready function of jQuery.https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/218520/

Answer (score 1):

1. Only input has value. It is an invalid attribute for span use `data-* attribute` for this

```js
var ar_value = $('.output').data('value'); 
console.log(ar_value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" data-value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>
```

alert

```js
var ar_value = $('.output').data('value');
alert(ar_value)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
  <center><b><span class="output" data-value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center>
</div>
```

Comment: I written by your style but i am getting undefined value by alerting that variable

Comment: @naniraju did you change in span? should be `data-value='1'`

Comment: can you update the OP with what you tried so I can see @naniraju

Comment: <div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" data-value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>

Comment: @naniraju something is causing the problem and I doubt I can help with out seeing a demo that does what you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, if you are using a class then there is likely to be more than one jquery has a handy method for this already. It will work just as well with only one element with .output too.

```js
$( ".output" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log($( this ).attr('value') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-10 ac">
<center><b><span class="output" value='1'>1</span> Child</b></center>
  <center><b><span class="output" value='2'>2</span> Child</b></center> 
</div>
```